# How to integrate CSS <style> tag into Smarty template?

Tags: css, smarty

I want to write CSS code into a  tag like this into Smarty template:

```
<style>
    a { color:#333333; }
</style>
```

Doesn't work: page shows in blank.

Any solution?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Escaping Smarty Parsing](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.escaping.tpl)

You're looking for `{literal}...{/literal}`.